# Does Instagram have API endpoints for media reach paid and impressions paid metrics?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Does the API have a way for me to get paid reach and paid impressions data of Instagram media? Is there any documentation about this?

When I submitted the request below, I expected organic reach + paid reach and organic impression + paid impression data.

```
<media id>/insights?metric=reach,impressions
```

However, the [Meta team's answer here](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/246956565984307/?join_id=f11582215aab27), indicates that the above returns only organic reach and organic impressions data in response. In addition, it is said that only the marketing API should be used to get paid access and paid impression data of Instagram media.

However, it is not stated in the documentation that only organic data is returned: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/insights

When I examined the marketing API documents, I noticed that the `adId` was used instead of the `mediaId`... but `mediaId` is not the same as `adId`

I want to know the paid reach and paid impression data of Instagram media. But there is no request listed that I can find to get this data in the marketing API documents.

For example, Facebook document posts have metrics where I can get paid reach and paid impressions.(post_impressions_paid, post_impressions_paid_unique, page_posts_impressions_paid, page_posts_impressions_paid_unique) -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v14.0/insights

Is there not an endpoint for paid reach and paid impression data available in the API?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/insights/

The API only reports organic interaction metrics; interactions on ads containing a media object are not counted.
Metrics data is stored for 2 years.